# When I scroll horizontally my absolutely positioned footer gets cut off

Tags: html, css

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
body {
z-index: 0;

width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 100px 0 0 0;
padding: 0;
}
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;

    width: 100vw;
    height: 100px;

    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #000000;

    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    letter-spacing: 25px;
}
```

How do I fix this?

Also any advice with sticky footers in general would be greatly appreciated. I'm struggling...

Comment: add your html part too

Comment: can you add your html code so we can debug it easily.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more about the structure of your HTML. For example you have some of your page content that is wider then others and you footer being at a set width is therefore getting left behind.

Try wrapping everything in a container, make sure that you use `width:100%;` then nothing inside that container should have a width of more than 100%

If something does. e.g. a section has `width:150%; then you get the problem you are facing now. as per this demo.

```css
header {
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: #333;
}

section {
  height: 70vh;
  width: 150%;
  background: #ccc;
}

footer {
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
  </header>
  <section>
  </section>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no difference between the two as the parent div has been set to width 100%. (I tried it to make sure I was correct)

Answer (score 0):

use  **overflow:hidden;** to avoid scrolling,I'm added the snippet below

```css
body {
z-index: 0;

width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 100px 0 0 0;
padding: 0;
}
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;

    width: 100vw;
    height: 100px;
  overflow:hidden;

    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #000000;

    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    letter-spacing: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  your footer 
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, your goal is to set footer on very bottom of the page.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/3aq3ts1a/) is example of such layout.

The trick is to position footer inside relatively positioned wrapper of required min-width. So it may work like

```
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: In this setup if you add content the footer doesn't stay on the bottom.

Comment: @ЩąđεЯօɮɛʀֆօπ if you need to always fix footer on bottom of the screen, why do you even use `position:absolute` instead of `position:fixed`? My setup positions footer on bottom of the screen or below depending on content height.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you probably want is `position: fixed`, `bottom: 0` and `width: 100%`.

EDIT:

What if you set a width for the page content, and then set the same width for your footer? See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f39hat2n/).

Comment: Then the footer will always be on the page which is not what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Oh I see. Hmm, I think you'll have to set a width for the page content, and then set the footer to the same width.

Comment: Where did you get this? "Absolute positioning is set at the time the page is first rendered, so if you scroll around, the element won't follow you.". Consider reading W3C specs more carefully.

Comment: Perhaps I worded it badly, but if you have a body element with width: 1000px, and you put a footer element inside it with position: absolute; bottom: 0; width: 100%, and your window is less than 1000px wide, the footer will render at the window width (i.e. < 1000px), and if you scroll horizontally, it will be clipped at that width and will never consume the full 1000px width of the parent element.

Comment: This happens because of positioning relatively to `body` element, which has scrollbar, so footers just moves along with it.